# Push records into store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a small table of values that are referenced in a lot of my tables.  I don't really want to create a different route in my api just for a hand full of values and all that so I'm just using store.push to push the models into the store like this:

```
     var store = this.get('store');
     store.push('item',{id:1,name:'Item 1'});
     store.push('item',{id:2,name:'Item 2'});
     store.push('item',{id:3,name:'Item 3'});
     store.push('item',{id:4,name:'Item 4'});
```

Originally, I was just doing this in the model for my `IndexController` which worked, but only if my app was accessed from the index route.  I need it loaded in my entire app.  I've tried doing it in an `init` function in `Ember.Application.create`, but that didn't work.  It looked like the store hadn't initialized yet.

Is there anywhere I can do this when the app starts up so that it's available everywhere?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in the `ApplicationRoute`, it's the root route, always hit, and only hit once.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(){
   //great place to inject
  }
});
```